# CONTEXT_ID added in SJS 0.9.0 is being set as null in the table

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Im trying to catch up with the new SJS 0.9.0 in my application. Once after the context is created , I am trying to submit a job -> this happens

```
19/04/10 21:45:06 ERROR JobDAOActor: About to restart actor due to exception:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "CONTEXT_ID" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (c144684e-3dad-459d-acff-2ac353709092, SJS_512_MB_shared_prioritized@1, 1, spark.jobserver.DPAASExecutor, 2019-04-10 21:45:06.602, null, null, null, null, null, null).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:366)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$InsertOrUpdateAction$$anonfun$nativeUpsert$1.apply(JdbcActionComponent.scala:560)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$InsertOrUpdateAction$$anonfun$nativeUpsert$1.apply(JdbcActionComponent.scala:557)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:347)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:407)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl.preparedInsert(JdbcActionComponent.scala:498)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$InsertOrUpdateAction.nativeUpsert(JdbcActionComponent.scala:557)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$InsertOrUpdateAction.f$1(JdbcActionComponent.scala:540)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$InsertOrUpdateAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:545)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcDriverAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:32)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcDriverAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:29)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/pull/1058 . This is the feature that has been added in SJS 0.9.0

Can you please explain me why this happens ? Should I include any extra prop like CONTEXT_ID while submitting the job , because this has been added only in SJS 0.9.0 and I have gone through this content https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/releases/tag/v0.9.0 .. Or is spark taking care of the CONTEXT_ID thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually because , we were using an earlier version of SJS (0.8.0) jar in the code and used the SJS 0.9.0 jar only in the job_server directory. It used the manager_start.sh which was required only in 0.8.0 and not in 0.9.0. Replaced with 0.9.0 it worked fine !!